# How to amend successive commits such that they reference other submodule commits?

Tags: git, git-submodules

After amending some commit messages in a submodule I figured I should also update the parent repositories' commits to repair the broken references.

So I did an interactive rebase on the parent repository. I wanted to amend two commits in the parent repository that refer to two other commits in the submodule, like this:

```
---A---B---C---D--- parent
   |   |
   v   v
---a---b--- sub
```

Therefore I do `git rebase -i A^` and choose to edit A and B:

```
edit A ...
edit B ...
pick C ...
pick D ...
```

Now I am at commit A. To restore the correct submodule commit ID I first check the relevant submodule commit out and then amend the commit in the parent repository.

```
$ cd sub/
$ git checkout a
$ cd ..
$ git add sub
$ git commit --amend
```

Seems good, so I continue to the next one:

```
$ git rebase --continue
```

Now it complains it could not merge. Here my translation from a localized message:

```
Error merging submodule sub (Commits do not follow any merge base)
automatic merge of sub
CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in sub
error: Could not apply B (B's commit message)
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm ", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply B (B's commit message)
```

Fair enough. The second commit has lost its connection to the first one because of the changed submodule ID in the first one. `git status` says `changed by both:    sub`. Unswervingly, I try to amend once again:

```
$ cd sub/
$ git checkout b
$ cd ..
$ git add sub
$ git commit --amend
```

Unfortunately this does not do what I want. The reason is that the erroneous `git rebase --continue` somehow ate commit B completely. B's changes were put in the staging area but the commit is gone. Therefore the second `git commit --amend` will amend A and put all changes from B into A! Now I guess I could create a new commit at that point, replicating B. But to get it exactly as B would be rather complicated.

How do I amend submodule references correctly? Why and under which circumstances does rebasing destroy commits like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: <s>Do the `git commit` without `--amend`</s> use `git rebase --continue`, which will do the `git commit` without `--amend`.

#### Longer

Let's take your original diagram, minus the connections to the submodule (since they're flimsy and get in the way :-) ):

> ```
> ...--o--A--B--C--D   <-- branch
> ```

You run `git rebase -i A^` and change `A` to `edit` (and so on).  Rebase cherry-picks `A` to a new copy `A'`:

```
...--o--A--B--C--D   <-- branch
      \
       A'  <-- HEAD
```

You make your update, `git add`, and `git commit --amend` to make new `A"`, leaving `A'` behind as abandoned:

```
       A"   <-- HEAD
      /
...--o--A--B--C--D   <-- branch
      \
       A'
```

Now, regardless of what you put in for instructions for `B`, Git *tries* to copy `B` *but fails*.  So the rebase stops at:

```
       A"   <-- HEAD
      /
...--o--A--B--C--D   <-- branch
      \
       A'
```

with some uncommitted changes in the index and work-tree.  **There is no commit `B'` yet.**  There are two things you do can do now.  One is to make it yourself:

```
<fix the submodule>
git add sub
git commit
```

This creates `B'`:

```
       A"-B'   <-- HEAD
      /
...--o--A--B--C--D   <-- branch
      \
       A'
```

and now you can `git rebase --continue` to have Git go on to the next part of the instructions (hence you don't need to ask to edit `B` originally, you can just go on to copy `C` to `C'` now: if Git now stops to let you edit `B'` you can just tell it to continue).

The other—since `git commit` now requires that you type in a commit message—is to set everything up, and instead of `git commit`, run `git rebase --continue` to make Git make `B'`:

```
<fix the submodule>
git add sub
git rebase --continue
```

The `--continue` step notices that all conflicts are fixed (or complains and stops if they're not), and then does the `git commit` and goes on, exactly as if you'd made the commit yourself.

#### Summary

You need `edit` as an instruction to make rebase stop and let you `--amend` a cherry-pick that will *succeed*.  You *don't* need `edit` for a commit where the cherry-pick will *fail*, as Git will stop without having made the commit in the first place.

It's hard to know in advance—in some cases, it might as well be impossible—to know which cherry-picks are going to succeed and which are going to fail.  So you wind up having to pay a lot of attention to the exact messages that come out just before `git rebase` stops to let you do something: did it stop because the cherry-pick *failed*, or did it stop because you told it to stop after the cherry-pick *succeeded?*  In other words, is there a commit that you should `--amend` now, or should you (have Git) make a *new* commit now?

(I get tripped up by this myself.  I find it pretty annoying.)

Comment: I'd rather not create a new commit because I would like to preserve the original message, author, date etc. automatically. Is there really no simple way to do this?

Comment: `git rebase` has set things up so that after you set everything up, `git rebase --continue` will create the commit for you. I should have mentioned that... There, edited to fix.

Comment: I see! And I guess I should have read the error message more carefully as it suggested the same thing...